# Crud MEAN Dron Geolocalization

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mean, angular-fullstack

I'm developing a fullstack web with Angular + express + nodejs + mongoDB and the project consists on a web with a map uploading constantly a market with the real position of a dron. My purpose is to update the map when express receive a post (from postman for example). This is my JS controller for coordinates.

```
router.get('/getLast', (req, res) =>{
Coordenadas.find((err, docs) => {
    if(!err){res.send(docs);}
    else{ console.log('Error al recibir las coordenadas: ' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)); }
}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(1);});

router.post('/', (req,res) =>{
var cor = new Coordenadas({
    lat: req.body.lat,
    lon: req.body.lon
});
cor.save((err, doc) =>{
    if(!err) res.send(doc);
    else { console.log('Error al recibir las coordenadas: ' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)); }
});});
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Well, the thing is that i can use setInterval in the function which invoques GET in database. But i would like to get a service which invoque that GET in the moment that a POST is produced